# TypeError: function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'njobs'

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I am working on a basic example of MCMC sampling for Bayesian estimation using PyMC3. I have a minimally working example of my code below:

```
# Establish the parameters of the model
p_a = .15
N = 150
n_successes_a = np.random.binomial(N, p_a)

# Build a model using the uniform prior and binomial
with pm.Model() as Model:
    # Prior on p
    prob = pm.Uniform('p')
    # Binomial likelihood
    y = pm.Binomial('y', n=N, p=prob, observed=n_successes_a)

# Begin to sample from the posterior distribution
with Model:
    samples = pm.sample(2000, njobs=1)
```

Then when I run this, I get the error: `TypeError: function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'njobs'`

Any insight as to why this might be happening? I have not been able to find anything online elsewhere providing a substantiative answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://docs.pymc.io/api/inference.html?highlight=sample#pymc3.sampling.sample

`sample()` doesn't accept a `njobs` argument. I'm guessing you meant to be setting the `cores` argument

Comment: Is this a result from a version change? I am watching a tutorial now that has the njobs keyword argument. Is cores essentially synonymous?

Comment: @Ethan yeah, [it was deprecated in PyMC 3.4](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/dfc9102b96c0eac72c0fa69b742ee81844ab46c4/RELEASE-NOTES.md#deprecations-2). But it's strange that it throws an error, since [the current code](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/v3.8/pymc3/sampling.py#L364) shows it will pass it along to `cores` for you, and issue a warning.